# Writing a Python script, and using PuTTY to talk to a piece of test equipment

Tags: python, putty

Let me start by stating I have not written code for many years, but I would like to learn Python.  I am using a piece of test equipment (8206 Omnia II electrical compliance analyzer box, by Associated Research) to make some manual measurements.  The testing is tedious, and what I really want to do is measure and store data at 30 second intervals to a *.csv file so I don't have to take pictures of the screen every 30 seconds.  There are commands listed in the 8206 box manual, and I would like to write code in Python to automate testing.  It sounds easy, but I don't know Python.  I have the PuTTY terminal emulator, and was wondering if knowledgeable person can tell me if this combination of PuTTy and Python will work. I want to learn Python, but I have an immediate need for the automation.

Will you please tell me if my expectations are realistic?
Thanks for your guidance.
Regards,
John

Comment: Are you ssh'd into the box? You should then start to find out how to interface with the box and read in data then the csv part will come easily.

Comment: You might reasonably use PuTTY to talk to the device manually (to verify your understanding of the commands, perhaps), but you wouldn't use it from Python - you'd talk to the device directly, using some sort of communications-related module (pyserial, ssh, etc. - I have no idea what sort of interface the device has).

Comment: All of this is definitely doable--your expectations are realistic. [Automate the Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/) (I'm not affiliated - just a fan) would help get you some of the basics.

Comment: I have to admit I do not know what SSH is other than its a protocol.  The test box has a RS-232, 9-pin connector and a USB A Plug to USB B Plug cable came with the box, which plugs in next to the RS-232.  I figure I can use that cable.  And so I was thinking I would use manual commands to test them, and then embed the commands in Python.  Like I said, I don't know this stuff.  Will you please add a little more detail as to the steps I would need to take to make this automation a reality?  Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Automate the Boring Stuff link.